# How to bind the directory to container while using camel?

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, apache-camel

Is is possible to bind the directory to container while using camel apache? I'm trying like:

```
from("kafka:xxx-xxx?brokers=localhost:9092")
 .setProperty("xxx", simple(procVers()))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_REPOSITORY, simple("xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_TAG, simple("xxx")) 
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_IMAGE_ID, simple("xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_IMAGE, simple("xxx:xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_NAME, exchangeProperty("xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_ENV, () -> new String []{
                        "MODE=xxx", "PARSER_CLIENT=xxx",
                        "PATHS=/home/xxx/xxx"  })
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_BINDS,simple("/xxx/:/xxx/"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID, simple("${body.id}"))
    .to("docker:containerstart?host=/var/run/docker.sock")
    .log("container started")
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID, simple("${body.id}"))
    .to("docker:containerwait?host=/var/run/docker.sock?")
    .log("container end");
```

but doesn't work, no error during runtime.

Comment: Hum, good question, I'm wondering if it is doable with the current code. Feel free to create a ticket for that

Comment: Where to create the ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL

Comment: BTW try to make your code minimal as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Will be possible starting from Camel 3.20

Comment: that is great! Anyway there's workaround for that, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround if somebody don't want to wait till next camel release.
You must add HostConfig instance within DOCKER_HOST_CONFIG.
example:

```
from("kafka:xxx-xxx?brokers=localhost:9092")
 .setProperty("xxx", simple(procVers()))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_REPOSITORY, simple("xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_TAG, simple("xxx")) 
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_IMAGE_ID, simple("xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_IMAGE, simple("xxx:xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_NAME, exchangeProperty("xxx"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_ENV, () -> new String []{
                        "MODE=xxx", "PARSER_CLIENT=xxx",
                        "PATHS=/home/xxx/xxx"  })
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_BINDS,simple("/xxx/:/xxx/"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID, simple("${body.id}"))
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_HOST_CONFIG, () -> 
                  HostConfig.newHostConfig().withBinds(new Bind(this.mount, new 
                  Volume(this.mount)))
                        .withMemory(2000000000L)
                        .withMemorySwap(20000000000L)
                        )
    .to("docker:containerstart?host=/var/run/docker.sock")
    .log("container started")
    .setHeader(DockerConstants.DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID, simple("${body.id}"))
    .to("docker:containerwait?host=/var/run/docker.sock?")
    .log("container end");
```